# Retrieving all numbers from a certain text file

Tags: c++

I have the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void tellen ()
{
    ifstream input;
    ofstream output;
    char kar;
    input.open ("test",ios::in);
    kar = input.get();
    while ( !input.eof() ){
        if ( kar >= '0' and kar <= '9'){
            cout << kar;
            kar = input.get();
        }
        else
            kar = input.get();

    }
    //cout << "Aantal characters:" << aantalchar << endl;
    //cout << "Aantal regels:" << aantalregels << endl;
}

int main()
{
    tellen();
    return 0;
} //main
```

What I intended this program to do is to show me all numbers in a certain text file ("Test" in this case) in the command window. I'm wondering why this doesn't work? I have a file called test but when I run this the command prompt gives me a blank. The problem persists when I change "test" to "test.txt". Does anyone have a clue what the problem is? Maybe it has to do with the location of the file?

Comment: while(!input.eof()) doesnt do what you think

Comment: what did the debugger show you? Does you code go through that loop?

Comment: @pm100 No bugs, the command prompt opens but doesn't show anything

Comment: i asked what the debugger shows. You have a bug - the code doesnt do what you expect - thats a bug. Use the debugger to step through the program

Comment: @pm100 "Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))"

Comment: you need to learn to use a debugger, what platform are you on?

Comment: @pm100 I'm using codeblocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will give you output of a txt file called test.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void tellen() {
    ifstream input;
    ofstream output;

    int kar;
    char charKar;
    input.open("test.txt", ios::in);

    // could replace "test.txt" with a variable such as filePath = "/downloads/test.txt"

    if (input.is_open()) {
        while (!input.eof()) {

            kar = input.get(); //kar gets inputed as an ASCII
            charKar = static_cast<char>(kar);//charKar converts the ASCII into a char variable



            if (charKar >= '0' && charKar <= '9'){ //Evaluate charKar, not kar

                 cout << charKar << endl;

            }



        }

        input.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "\nFile Did Not Open!";
    }


}

int main() {

    tellen();

    return 0;
} //main
```

I have tested the code and it works! Sorry if it's messy I was making eggs while coding this so if you have any questions just ask!

Comment: `input >> kar` will get larger integers than just a digit value (i.e, it will parse strings of digits and not get individual digits).  if the string of digits is large enough, it could do something unexpected.  its not the same result as `kar = input.get()`

Comment: @Les I'm so sorry! If you look back at the code I have edited it and it is now correct! I'm sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

Things to change:

1. Add a check to make sure that the file was opened successfully.
2. Use type `int` when reading characters using `istream::get()` instead of `char`.
3. Change the `while` statement a bit.

```
void tellen (){
    ifstream input;
    ofstream output;

    input.open ("test",ios::in);
    if ( !input )
    {
       std::cerr << "Unable to open file.\n";
       return;
    }

    int kar; // Don't use char.
    while ( (kar = input.get()) != EOF  ){
        if ( kar >= '0' and kar <= '9'){
           cout.put(kar); // I prefer this.
           // cout << (char)kar;
        }
    }
    //cout << "Aantal characters:" << aantalchar << endl;
    //cout << "Aantal regels:" << aantalregels << endl;
}
```

Comment: When I try to run this I get an error "undefined reference to WinMain@16" which I did not get previously

Comment: @YakSalTafri If you mindlessly cut and pasted R Sahu's modification over top of your source you will no longer have a main function.

Comment: @YakSalTafri - replace only your `tellen` function with R Sahu's `tellen` function.

Comment: @user4581301 Nice assumption on your part, I didn't mindlessly copy and paste it, I fidgeted with it before I asked.

Comment: @YakSalTafri I certainly could have worded that better. I apologize.